# Put Bucket request return 403 Forbidden and Error code: AccessDenied

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am using Object Storage Service - Put Bucket ACL on Alibaba Cloud Instance. As PutBucketACL interface is used to modify the access permissions for a bucket. Using below mentioned request syntax.

```
PUT /? acl HTTP/1.1
x-oss-acl: Permission
Host: BucketName.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com
Date: GMT Date
Authorization: SignatureValue
```

I am getting **403 Forbidden** message and Error Code is showing as **AccessDenied**.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

For your request, the result should be introduced like follows

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-oss-request-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Date: GMT Date
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server: AliyunOSS

If it fails and throws an error like **403 Forbidden** then you are not authorized to change the bucket ACL permissions.

Please check the following to ensure the access

> - Check whether you have enough permission to change the bucket permission (Bucket Owernership)
> - Check whether you are using the correct Accesskey Pairs
> - Check the host (This also may cause 403 Forbidden error)